# Slash at the end of url

Tags: url, replace

I think (correct me if I am wrong) that it is better to put a / at the end of most of url. Like this: http://www.myweb/file/

And not put / at the end of filenames: http://www.myweb/name.html

I have to correct that in a website with a lot of links. Is there a way I can do that in a fast way. For instance in some programs like Dreamweaver I can use find and replace.

The second case is quite easy with Dreamweaver:
- Find: .html/"
- Replace: .html"

But how can I say something like:
- Find: all the links that end with a directory. Like  http://www.myweb/file
- Replace: the same link but with a / at the end. Like http://www.myweb/file/

Comment: You can use regular expressions and search `.` in url

Comment: Write some kind of generator to search for patterns and replace them. I do that always for replacing patterns in a whole workspace.

Comment: There's no guarantee that file names include a `.` and/or that directory names do not. Unless you know the actual file system structure, there's no way to distinguish between them in URLs.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you've to scan for **files** in a recursive way. Then you can look for `href=` or something else and replace it with the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach *may* work but it is based on the assumption that all files have a file extension.

There is a distinct difference between the urls `http://www.myweb/file` and `http://www.myweb/file/` because the latter could resolve to `http://www.myweb/file/index.php`, or any other in the default set configured in your web server. That URL could also reference a perfectly valid file which doesn't contain a file extension, such as if it were a REST endpoint.

So you are correct insofar as you should explicitly add a "/" if you are referring to a directory, for example if you are expecting the web server to look up the correct index page to respond, or doing a directory listing.

To replace the incorrect URLS, [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) are your friend.

To find all files which have an erroneous "/" you could use `/\.(html|php|jpg|png)\//`, adding as many different file extensions into that pipe-separated list as you like. You can then replace that with `.$1` or `.\1` depending on your tool.

An example of doing this with Perl would be:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\.(html|php|jpg|png)\//.\1/g' theFileYouWantToCheck.html
```

Of (if you're using a Linux-based system) you can automate that nicely with `find`:

```
find path/to/html/root -type f -name "*.html* | xargs perl -pi -e 's/\.(html|php|jpg|png)\//.\1/g'
```

which will find all html files in the directory and do an inline find and replace. Assuming you're using version control, it's then easy to see the changes it's applied :)

**Update** 
Solving the problem for adding a slash to directories isn't trivial. The approach I'd take:

- Write a script to recurse through your website structure locally, making a list of all files
- Parse the HTML files to extract all `href=".*"` and replace them with `href=".*/"` only if the end of the URL isn't present in the list extracted by the first script.

Any text-based find and replace is not going to be aware of whether the link is actually to a file or not.

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain it well. Please see my updated my question.